# numpy - select the rows where a column is equal in two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
a = 
[[ 461.  0.  ]
 [ 480.  15. ]
 [ 463.  28. ]]
```

and

```
b = 
[[ 463.  0.  ]
 [ 462.  8.  ]
 [ 466.  15. ]
 [ 469.  22. ]
 [ 470.  28. ]
 [ 473.  34. ]]
```

I need a resulting array comprised of `a` minus `b` only if the second column of `a => [0 15 28]`  is in the second column of `b => [0 8 15 22 28 34]`. All elements of the second column of `a` will be in the second column of `b`, I just want to discard those in `b` that don't exist in `a`. The expected result is:

```
result =
[[  -2.  0.  ]
 [  14.  15. ]
 [  -7.  28. ]]
```

To begin, I thought of getting the 'subarray' of `b` that contains just the rows I'm interested in. Among many other things, the one I thought would work (and didn't) was this:

```
result = b[b[:, 1] in a[:, 1]] # not working
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can there be duplicate values of the second column in `b`?  For example, could you have two rows such that `(466,15)` and perhaps `(469,15)`?

Comment: @rayryeng No, they are a result of np.unique(), both the second columns of `a` and `b`.

Comment: One more question.  Will there ever be a case where there's a value in the second column of `a` where it is **not** in `b`?  For example, what if `a = [[461,0], [480,15], [463,100]]`?... that is, if the second column has a value 100 which is not seen in `b`?  Apologies for the questions.  I'd like to get my facts straight before I write an answer.

Comment: Another question: Are you guaranteed that the columns of both `a` and `b` are sorted?

Comment: @rayryeng No. Based on my problem, the second column of `a` will always be a subset of the second column of `b`.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, both second columns are sorted. The first columns, no.

Comment: Aside: if you're finding yourself needing this kind of alignment, you're probably going to have an easier time with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) than with bare numpy .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This algorithm works under the following assumptions:

1. The second column of `a` is a subset of the second column of `b`.  This means that we are guaranteed to find a value in the second column of `b` given a value in the second column of `a`.
2. The second columns of `a` and `b` are sorted.
3. There are no duplicate values in the second column shared between `a` and `b`.

---

Use [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to figure out if the corresponding value in the second column of `b` can be found in `a`.  You can then use this Boolean array to slice into `b` and do your subtraction with the first column of `a` and the first column of sliced result of `b`.  The reason why this works is because of the nature of the sorted order in `b`.  When slicing into this array in conjunction with `numpy.in1d`, you are guaranteed to have the second column of this sliced result match up exactly in values with the first column of `a`.  Once you have this alignment, you can subtract the first column of this sliced result with the first column of `a`.  To finish things up, you can copy over the second column of the sliced values of `b` and stack both of these together:

```
In [119]: import numpy as np

In [120]: a = np.array([[461,0],[480,15],[463,28]], dtype=np.float)

In [121]: b = np.array([[463,0], [462,8], [466,15], [469,22], [470,28], [473,34]], dtype=np.float)

In [122]: ind = np.in1d(b[:,1], a[:,1])

In [123]: np.column_stack([a[:,0]-b[ind,0], b[ind,1]])
Out[123]: 
array([[ -2.,   0.],
       [ 14.,  15.],
       [ -7.,  28.]])
```

What is returned from `numpy.in1d` is a Boolean array that tells you whether the ith value in the first input of `numpy.in1d` can be found **anywhere** in the second input of `numpy.in1d`.  To see what this looks like, given your data, we get:

```
In [124]: ind
Out[124]: array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

As you can see, both the first, third and fifth values in `b` can be found in `a`.  We simply slice into `b` and extract the right rows and these rows of the sliced result will have the second column values line up exactly with those second column values in `a`.  We then subtract the first columns of both `a` and the intermediate result together.

---

A more clean approach would be to slice into `b` and extract the entire matrix instead of just the first column, then just subtract the first column with `a` and this intermediate result:

```
In [125]: out = b[ind]

In [126]: out[:,0] = a[:,0] - out[:,0]

In [127]: out
Out[127]: 
array([[  -2.,   0.],
       [  14.,  15.],
       [  -7.,  28.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the conditions in your comments, the following should work:

```
def calculate_diffs(b, a):
    brow = b[:, 1]
    arow = a[:, 1]
    # Find common indices.  For your example, indices == [0, 2, 4]
    indices = numpy.searchsorted(brow, arow)
    r = a.copy()
    r[:, 0] = b[indices, 0] - a[:, 0]
    return r
```